# Changing android support repository installation path

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-support-library

I have changed my laptop and copied my android sdk from the old laptop to the new one. Now I want to update my android support repository and during installation it fails and says the system cannot find the specified path and the path it shows is the path in the old pc(i.e

> C:\Users\visas\AppData\Local\Temp\PackageOperation07\android\repository\android_m2repository_r47.zip).
>   How can I change this path to that of the new pc(i.e
>   C:\Users\id\AppData\Local\Temp\PackageOperation07\android\repository\android_m2repository_r47.zip)

Answer (score 0):

You can reinstall the sdk and then copy paste your data to it and have setting from scrap. and don't copy paste the tools file.

Or you can cut the contents of the files that look like a setting file in tools and see which one it is if things blow paste it back. second one seems fun.